# Default stylesheet always loads [OpenCart Theming]

Tags: opencart

I have just started on designing for Opencart. The page [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=43_44) says

> OpenCart uses a "default theme fallback system". This means that if you are missing a file in your custom theme folder, it will search the main "default" theme folder for the file.

Now i have created a folder stylesheet inside my template folder with all the files in the default directory. All css files except the stylesheet.css loads from my directory.

What am I missing? I have checked the spelling of stylesheet.css and even re-created it many times but still it loads from default directory.

Can anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When OpenCart says that it falls back, it literally means the template folder, that is

```
/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/
```

The stylesheet folder is outside of that, so you would need to add that manually to your theme `<head>` if you want to include the default stylesheet

### EDIT

If you want your stylesheet to be loaded, you need to edit the template in

```
/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/header.tpl
```

and change the path in there

Comment: I don't want to include the default css I want my own css to load but it doesn't. I have the stylesheet.css in my woodtheme/stylesheet/ folder but still it falls back.

Answer (score 1):

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />

needs to be changed in header.tpl

I had copied it from the default directory